# Cannot install Ubuntu on lenovo g50-80

Tags: ubuntu, lenovo-laptop

> I have installed Ubuntu successfully, but i failed to use windows to boot Ubuntu. I get a warning like this:
>   Your machine is currently booting in EFI mode. Due to limitations by Microsoft, many of EasyBCD's multi-booting features cannot be used in EFI mode and have been disabled.
>   [I got a warning like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUhFG.png)

Comment: Sounds like your Windows was installed in UEFI mode. Was your Ubuntu though?

Comment: When i changed to legacy it still do not work. By the way , can you speak Chinese...

Comment: Yes I do. Join this and we'll talk there: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37181/boot-ubuntu-with-windows-boot-manager

Comment: I'm sorry....My reputation is less than 20 so I can't talk there.

Comment: So you changed what to legacy? How exactly did you configured with EasyBCD? EFI chainloading grub or the kernel directly? Can you show a screenshot or something about your configuration? Why are you even using EasyBCD/Windows Boot Manager to do multi-boot btw?

Comment: I have changed boot priority to legacy first. Besides when i installed Ubuntu, I put boot in  /boot, my classmates told me that doing this can boot Ubuntu from Windows.. I have edited my question and i got a warning from EasyBCD when i  tried to add a boot Item.

Comment: It's pointless to change your boot priority. Your Windows is apparently installed in UEFI mode (implied by the EasyBCD warning) and you cannot legacy boot it anyway (at least without not some extra hacking and an extra bootloader). As for the EasyBCD part, I am not sure about its capability, like whether it can chainload grub2 EFI or the kernel/initramfs directly somehow. Maybe I will test it a bit and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

As the warning itself has told, EasyBCD cannot help you to make the UEFI version of Windows Boot Manager to load Linux for you.

Obviously your Windows was installed in UEFI mode, and you haven't / couldn't tell whether your Ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode too (or in legacy mode with CSM). So your best option now is probably to install rEFInd (http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), since it can be installed in Windows and should be able to load Ubuntu for you no matter it's installed in UEFI mode or legacy mode.

If you insist on sticking with EasyBCD (e.g. no intention to learn about UEFI or other bootloaders), then you'll need to reinstall your Windows in legacy mode.